# Load .RData file in Shiny App with load command in global.R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to have my app read .Rdata file with in the project directory, but some how I am not able to make it work, here is an example of what i am trying to do,

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(dataTableOutput("text"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$text <- renderTable({
        fileText <- data1()
        fileText
    })
}

global.R
data1 <- load(file = './data1.RData', envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Have you tried loading it inside your ```server``` function? Did it work?

Comment: yes, but even that did not work for me

Comment: @Vikram I deleted my answer as it works for `RDS` and other file formats.  And I strongly suggest switching from `Rdata` to them.